# What is the correct way of updating the resource translations strings of a react-i18next instance? Do I init it again with the new JSON?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, i18next, react-i18next

The documentation of react-i18next shows that this is how we initialize the instance:

```
i18n.use(initReactI18next).init({
    resources: {
        en: {
            translations,
        },
    },
    load: 'languageOnly',
    lng: 'en',
});
```

Let's say I get new updated translations and I want my application to update and show these new translations - do I just initialize the instance again like this:

```
i18n.use(initReactI18next).init({
    resources: {
        en: {
            newTranslations,
        },
    },
    load: 'languageOnly',
    lng: 'en',
});
```

or is there a smarter way? If I initialize the instance again, should I somehow destroy the previous one, or would it destroy on its own?